# Using External Monitor & Camera with Macbook Pro

Tags: display, webcam, video-conference

I have a Macbook Pro 2019 with decent spec. I plug it into a normal 21" external monitor. I also use an external webcam for my video call (Logitech C920e).

This is a very normal workflow. But the problem is, every time I have a video call, specially if I do screenshare, the CPU usage goes 100% and everything comes to halt. My audio and video falls out of sync, and everything becomes irresponsive.

When I check the Activity Monitor, it's just the system using that mach CPU. There is no special process causing this.

I've turned off Software Acceleration in Chrome, but that's not the problem. The issue still exist. Also, I have the same problem if I do video recording using OBS.

Any idea what is the problem?

PS:

The MBP specs are 2.4 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9, Graphics: AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 4 GB Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB, 64GB RAM

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the CPU tab of Activity Monitor taken when the CPU load is high (sorted by CPU%)? Also, does the problem only occur with the Logitech cam or also with the builtin one?

Comment: I will capture one and attach. The problem does not happen with the built-in camera, but the quality of that is a lot lower. I think the problem is with Mac's GPU not being able to process the entire screen and the camera input, putting the load on CPU and CPU getting overloaded.

Comment: Does the problem occur if you use the Logitech cam *without* the 21" monitor (just the built-in on)?

Comment: If I take the external monitor out, the problem can happen again, but likely later (like after 30 min instead of 10 min of video call). If I use built-in camera, I won't face this problem. Of course, the quality of the built-in camera is very bad!.